# Copy and paste template from current workbook's worksheet to a new workbook's worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create a new worksheet in a new workbook with a specific name that is given in MyNewSheetName variable. I don't really want a specific name for the new workbook but it would be nice to have one. To avoid confusion I will name my current workbook "workbook 1" and the new workbook I want to create "workbook 2". Currently I have a template that contains the worksheet in the workbook 1 that I want to be copied over in the newly created workbook 2. Then, on that worksheet I want to copy and paste values that are in the worksheet in workbook 1 where the macro button is located.

I was able to do this with the following code but only on the same workbook. However, I can't figure out how to copy over the template to a new workbook and then copy and paste the values on that workbook's worksheet. Is something like this possible?

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

    worksheetName = ActiveSheet.Name
    MyNewSheetName = "packing list"
    
    Sheets("PackingTemplate").Copy After:=Sheets("PackingTemplate")
    ActiveSheet.Name = MyNewSheetName
    
    Dim lastrow As Long, erow As Long
    
    With Worksheets(worksheetName)
        erow = 21
        lastrow = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        
        For i = 8 To lastrow
            If .Cells(i, x).Value <> "" Then
                Worksheets(MyNewSheetName).Range("a22").EntireRow.Insert
            End If
        Next i

        For i = 8 To lastrow
            If .Cells(i, x).Value <> "" Then
                .Cells(i, x).Copy
                Worksheets(MyNewSheetName).Cells(erow, 1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
                .Cells(i, 3).Copy
                Worksheets(MyNewSheetName).Cells(erow, 3).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
                .Cells(i, 2).Copy
                Worksheets(MyNewSheetName).Cells(erow, 2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
                erow = erow + 1
            End If
        Next i
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Save workbook1 and then saveas workbook2?

Comment: Save workbook1 and then create a copy with "filecopy"